# How is it possible for rm to throw "not a directory" and "is a directory errors"?

Tags: mac-osx, rm

I got a strange error the other day. Attempting to `rm -rf nav/` a directory threw "not a directory", but trying to `rm nav` errored with "is a directory".

How is this possible?

[image: not a directory]
<sub>(source: [zastica.com](http://public.zastica.com/not-a-directory.png))</sub>

Comment: Well, what *is* it, then?  What's "ls -l nav" show?

Answer (score 1):

You may have some filesystem corruption. Notice the `1` between the permission and the owner? That's the number of links to the directory inode. A directory should normally have a minimum of two, because it is linked to by the parent directory, and by itself (the `.` entry it contains). I would guess there is some corruption and your `nav` directory does not contain a `.` entry. Can you get anything with `ls -la nav`?

Comment: The file/directory is already gone unfortunately, so I can't ls -la nav.